# find phase greater than 2*pi in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, phase, complex

I'm working on extracting the phase information in a given signal in MATLAB. I've the following vector;

```
signal = [exp(1i*10) exp(1i*100) exp(1i*1000) exp(1i*10000)];
```

When I use angle function in MATLAB to calculate the phase value, it returns the following result.

```
angle(signal) = -2.5664   -0.5310    0.9735   -2.8310
```

I want to calculate the original phase values, as follows,

```
  [10 100 1000 10000];
```

1. How to find the original phase values above interval [-π,π] in MATLAB?

Comment: Your map is many-to-one, it cannot be inverted.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to find actual phase information, without scaling by 2*pi.

Comment: Measuring the angle of a wheel does not tell you how many full rotations is has done to get there. I'm not sure what you're not understanding.

Comment: I'm not interested in measuring the angle. I only want to find out the phase value. For ex: Phase value may contain frequency offset value. In that case, I'm not interested in just angle, but the entire phase value, so that I could extract the frequency offset value.

Answer (score 3):

You can, *if* you increase phase between samples slowly enough, using `unwrap(angle(signal))`. "Slowly enough" means the phase doesn't jump by more than $2 \pi$; `unwrap` works by tracking "total phase". Python equivalent implementation [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1488) (note you can configure `discont` there for jumps greater than $\pi$ (or [TOL](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html)) but it's pointless with `angle` since it outputs within $[-\pi, \pi]$).

Otherwise, can't, as described by others. For an infinite number of inputs, you get the same output, like asking "what's $N$ in $N\ \%\ 2 = 0$" (division by 2 remainder).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

$y = e^{ix}, x \in \mathbb{R} $ is a many to one relationship , that means it's not uniquely invertible. Angles are periodic in $2\pi$ so there is no reason to. $10000$ and $10000+2*pi$ are the SAME anle.

Comment: Thanks. It's disappointing. I could see the values but it's unfortunate that I can't calculate it.