# How to Frequency Modulate an Audio Signal

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, time-frequency, frequency-modulation

I've started to learn about FM and I followed [this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhZ8a.png) to FM a sine wave.

I have managed to do it and here is the result:

[image]

And the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


BasebandFrequency = 10e3
CarrierFrequency = 100e3
SamplingFrequency = 1e7
BufferLength = 2000
modulation_index = 4
t = np.arange(0, 2000, 1 / BufferLength)
BasebandSignal = np.sin(2*np.pi*t / (SamplingFrequency/BasebandFrequency))
CarrierSignal = np.sin(2*np.pi*t / (SamplingFrequency/CarrierFrequency))

BasebandSignal_integral = -np.cos(2*np.pi*t / (SamplingFrequency/BasebandFrequency))

ModulatedSignal_FM = np.sin((2*np.pi*t / (SamplingFrequency/CarrierFrequency)) + (modulation_index * BasebandSignal_integral))

plt.plot(t, ModulatedSignal_FM)
plt.plot(t, BasebandSignal)
plt.show()
```

I tried following his other guide about [FM an Audio file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhZ8a.png) but I can't understand how to do it,

[here is the audio file I'm using](https://ufile.io/rodvknnb)

This is what I came up with so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import statistics

def generateSignalFM(time_vector,data):
    TWO_PI = 2 * np.pi
    fc = 80000
    b = 25
    fm = np.sin(TWO_PI * (fc + b * data) * time_vector)

    return fm

def normalizeAudio(data):
    return np.float32(data / max(data))

def averageAudio(data):
    return np.float32(data / statistics.mean(data))

def main():
    SAMPLE_FOR = 1 # in seconds

    time_vector, data, sample_rate = readAudioFile('Recording.wav',SAMPLE_FOR,5)
    split_data = data[0:2000]
    split_time = time_vector[0:2000]
    audio_integrated = []
    for i in range(2000):
        audio_integrated.append(integrate.trapezoid(split_data[0:i]))
    audio_integrated = averageAudio(audio_integrated)
    audio_integrated = normalizeAudio(audio_integrated)
    fm = generateSignalFM(split_time,audio_integrated)
    plot_graph2d(split_time,split_data,split_time,fm)
```

And the result:

[image]

I am honestly lost, I managed to almost fully understand how to FM a sine wave but how do I do it with an Audio Signal?

Comment: It'd help to attach sample data of interest (e.g. Drive, [ufile](https://ufile.io/), [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)).

Comment: I added the audio file recording. @OverLordGoldDragon

Comment: Exactly the same way, you just use an audio signal instead of a sine wave?

Comment: I can't see much from the result, but why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Yes @user253751

Comment: I assume it is wrong because I know you shouldn't Frequency Modulate an Audio signal like a sine wave @Paddy

Comment: It has been a while since I have done any FM/AM stuff, but I don't know see why it wouldn't work like it would for a sine wave. The best course of actions in this case would be to try and demodulate it and see if you get back the original audio signal. I think it should. Leave a comment here if it does not work which should give me and others something to work with. Also post your demodulation code.

Comment: I wrote on one interpretation of your question which yields meaningful results. Note this isn't same as modulating individual frequencies, as in _independent components_, which is a much more difficult task, but I figure that's not your goal.

Comment: The guide link seems to erroneously link to the first image file.

Comment: You are integrating your sine wave but not your audio signal - why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Algorithm

To encode a signal $x_m$ in a carrier with frequency $f_c$, we [proceed as](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Frequency_modulation):

$$
y(t) = \cos(\phi(t)), \\
\phi(t) = 2\pi \cdot \left(f_c t + f_\Delta \int_0^t x_m(\tau)d\tau \right)
$$

where $f_\Delta$ controls the maximum deviation of $y$'s instantaneous frequency from $f_c$ (effectively its bandwidth, but not in strict Fourier sense).

Discrete-time implementation is as follows:

1. Integrate via cumulative sum
2. Ensure $t$ is sampled properly per sampling frequency, i.e. $f_s = 1 / (t[1] - t[0])$. In Python this means `linspace(t_min, t_max, N / (t_max - t_min), endpoint=False)`
3. Ensure $\phi(t)$ [does not exceed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70594/50076) $\pi$, adjusting $f_\Delta$ as necessary
4. Ensure $f_c \leq f_s/2 - f_\Delta$, where $f_s$ is sampling frequency.

#### Applied example

Doing all of the above for the first 1 second of OP's attached data yields below, which is validated with direct inspection, and using synchrosqueezed CWT with an extremely time-localized wavelet:

[image]

Zooming (note, CWT is logscale, so it appears "stretched"):

[image]

Zooming even more, and showing the result:

[image]

#### Code

Available at [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/main/SignalProcessing/Q76463%20-%20FM%20-%20Frequency%20Modulating%20a%20Signal/main.py).

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer, it will take me some time to actually understand it so I might ask you some questions here, firstly what does `data /= (2*np.abs(data).max())` do to the data? Normalize it?

Comment: @yarinCohen To ensure the values are between $[-.5, .5]$, so that $\cdot 2\pi$ is between $[-\pi, \pi]$ (as stated in code). $x$ is treated as instantaneous frequency, and integrating it gives phase, whose `diff` (in this case simply $x$) absolute value must be $<\pi$ to avoid aliasing. -- If my answers have been helpful, consider voting on them.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late question but why is `fc` arbitrary? I noticed when I modulate a 1 second of 44.1KHz with `fc=2000` That looks good and accurate but if I modulate a 10 seconds of the same audio with `fc=2000` it doesn't look accurate at all

Comment: @yarinCohen Not entirely arbitrary; the idea is, rapid frequency variations are better encoded at a higher mean frequency, `fc` - but if it's too high, we risk aliasing as modulations cross Nyquist. (It's "better" as in more accurate - in terms of audio quality I've little clue, but probably good idea to keep `fc` around input's mean frequency or below max)

Comment: Can you try modulating the same audio sound but 30 seconds of it? I can't find the best carrier frequency to use. At the moment I'm using 75KHz and it's not really accurate

Comment: @yarinCohen What I'd do: (1) trial & error; (2) if that fails, _squash_ original waveform between a min and a max somehow, to avert crossing into Nyquist --> repeat (1). The 'squashing' can include clipping or a nonlinear transform. Problem with raw timeseries is they're unbounded so no `fc` will ever be satisfactory in general case.